# How do I establish a connection to dashDB from IDA?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ida, dashdb

I'm trying to generate a physical data model on Bluemix using InfoSphere Data Architect running on my local machine.  I have a dashDB service up and running and know all the connection settings.  I can't seem to set up a connection from IDA to my dashDB instance and am looking for guidance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To get the best possible response, it's a good idea to include the approaches you tried so far (with code) and any error messages you are getting. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on asking good questions.

Answer (score 0):

From a dashDB perspective here all the details one would need to know on how to connect with dashDB. I will leave the IDA side of things for someone else to answer.

**[Connecting applications to the dashDB database](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/connecting/connecting_applications_to_dashdb_database.html)**

Answer (score 0):

While researching something else I came across this basic guide. Not sure if this will help. **[Connecting InfoSphere Data Architect to dashDB](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/connecting/connect_connecting_ibm_data_architect.html)**